# Python number guessing game

Tags: python, while-loop, python-3.3

I have found some practice problems online and I got most of them to work, but this one has stumped me. Its not homework so I'm not getting a grade.  However, there isn't a solution provided so the only way to get the answer is by doing it.

The task asks for you to write a problem that plays a number guessing game for numbers 1-100. However, this one tries to guess the users number by interval guessing, such as `[1, 100]` and generates the next question by using `first+last/2`.

I have a sample run from the site.

> Think of a number between 1 and 100 (inclusive).
>   Answer the following questions with letters y or Y for yes and n or N for no.
>   interval: [1,100]. Is your number <= 50? y
>   interval: [1,50]. Is your number <= 25? y
>   interval: [1,25]. Is your number <= 13? y
>   interval: [1,13]. Is your number <= 7? n
>   interval: [8,13]. Is your number <= 10? n
>   interval: [11,13]. Is your number <= 12? y
>   interval: [11,12]. Is your number <= 11? y
>   Your number is:  11

Here is my code so far, but I don't even quite know where to start because a while-loop constantly gives me an infinite loop.  I know the "middle" number needs to be an integer or else it'll be an infinite loop, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

```
x = input("Is your numbr <=50?")
count = 100
while x=="y" or "Y":
    count = count/2
    x = input("Is your number <=",count,"?")
    print(count)
```

If anyone has any tips it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem with your `while` loop is that `x=="y" or "Y"` doesn't mean what you think it does. You want `x=="y" or x=="Y"`, or `x in ('y', 'Y')`.

Comment: The expression `x=="y" or "Y"` is evaluated as `(x=="y") or "Y"` (the parentheses illustrate order of evaluation).  Since a non-empty string is always `True`, it is like `(x=="y") or True`, which is *always* `True`.  You probably want `x in ("y", "Y")`, or better yet, `x.lower() == "y"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire idea of the problem is to keep both "bounds" starting at 1 and 100, and each time you make a question "is you number <= X" you discard half of the range according to the answer, you are not doing this in your current solution.

like this.

```
lower = 1
high = 100
mid = (high + lower)/2 -> at start it will be 50
```

If the user answers Yes then you take the range from the current lower bound to the mid of the range, otherwise you continue with the range starting on mid+1 to the end, like this:

If user answers Yes:

```
high = mid
```

If user answers No:

```
lower = mid +1
```

The last part of the idea is to detect when the range lower-high contains only 2 numbers, or are the same number like this [11,12], you use the final answer of the user to choose the correct answer and the program terminates, the full code is here so you can test it:

```
found = False
range_lower_bound = 1
range_high_bound = 100

print "Think of a number between 1 and 100 (inclusive)."
print "Answer the following questions with letters y or Y for yes and n or N for no."

while not found:
    range_mid = (range_high_bound + range_lower_bound) / 2
    x = raw_input('interval: [%s,%s]. Is your number <= %s? ' % (range_lower_bound, range_high_bound, range_mid))
    if x.lower() == 'y':
        # Check if this is the last question we need to guess the number
        if range_mid == range_lower_bound:
            print "Your number is %s" % (range_lower_bound)
            found = True
        range_high_bound = range_mid
    # here i'm defaulting "anything" no N for simplicity
    else:
        # Check if this is the last question we need to guess the number
        if range_mid == range_lower_bound:
            print "Your number is %s" % (range_high_bound)
            found = True
        range_lower_bound = range_mid + 1
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: YES!! Thank you so much for breaking it down, it helps me see what exactly i should think when trying to figure the problem out. Only question i have is where did you make the numbers a float? shouldnt they just be an int? as in why does it print <=50.5 instead of <=50?

EDIT- nevermind my question, i noticed the / instead of //. Thanks again so much, this problem really had me stumped

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```
while x=="y" or "Y":
```

the expression "Y" will always evaluate to true.

You want

```
while x == "y" or x == "Y":
```

Even then, this will end the loop when the user types an "N". A working loop would be something like:

```
finished = False
while not finished:
    if x == "y":
        upper -= (upper-lower)/2
        # prompt for input
    elif x == "n":
        lower += (upper-lower)/2
        # prompt for input
    if upper == lower or (upper - 1) == lower:
        finished = True
        # final output
```

You should be able to fill in the blanks from there.

Comment: You don't need the `finished` flag for anything here; just `break` in the last step.

Comment: You'll need to do some parity checking, this will get stuck if upper=12 and lower=11.

Comment: while x.lower() == 'y':

Comment: while x in ['y', 'Y']:

Comment: This is true about my while statement. I can't believe i did that and didn't notice. your working loop also completely makes sense. I understand how you did everything, i just wish i would've known how to implement my knowledge like you did :( . Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One good idea would be to have a simple `while True:` loop, inside which you maintain a maximum guess and a minimum guess. You then ask the user whether their number is greater than the average of the two. If it is, update your minimum guess to the average. If not, you lower your maximum guess to the average. Repeat until the two guesses are equal, at which point you have found the number, and can break out of the infinite loop.

You'll have to do some simple parity checking of course, to make sure you actually change your guesses in each round. You should really use `raw_input()` for strings, `input()` is for python-formatted data.